# Should I revert an edit (overuse of code)?

Tags: discussion

A answer of mine at https://askubuntu.com/posts/215521/revisions was edited with several additional code tags to highlight program names.

To me it makes the question look overcrowded and drowns out the actual code posted.

Is it just me or should this edit be reverted?

Comment: Please understand that I have no problem with people editing my answers to make them better. This one just looks off to me.

Comment: I just down-voted because I don't think the edit should be reverted. Perfectly fine question to ask though.

Answer (score 5):

Highlighting commands is helpfull in some pleases, and in this case at least some are helpfull: this part of a sentence (not quoted to keep the origional layout)

progress of dd once it's running

can be a bit confusing. What is that word? what do you mean by that? Now you can emphasise it by making it bold, but that's a different meta-style: you are emphasising it, not saying it is something different.

By making it

progress of `dd` once it's running

It is clear that it is a command you can type, and therefore somthing to 'read' in a special way. The sentence is a bit overflowing with commands as it is, but I think it's better then the alternative: non-marked "code" / commands in a sentence that could be confusing.

If you want to improve the answer you might refrase the sentances a bit to keep the repeating mention of `dd` out of there. The sentence beginning with "This will display" does mention `dd` quite a bit more then needed maybe.

But overall I think it's allright as it is now.

Comment: I agree. These code blocks are used for the right reason. Looks a little odd but there you go. I've just fixed the full-block code segments.

Comment: Thanks Oli, it looks better.